# How to add jenkins slave nodes in jenkins master server using Chef cookbook

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, chef-recipe, master-slave, cookbook

I need  to work on how we can easily add new slave in Jenkins, using chef i.e configuring it with required jdk, chef client, git client etc.I have to write a cookbook for that. Can anybody give a starting point for that.

I already have a master jenkins in place. How can I add a a slave with jdk, chef client and git with help of chef recipe.

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for a starting point. A  sample cookbook.

Comment: https://learn.chef.io/

Comment: See: https://github.com/myspotontheweb/chef-jenkins-farm

Answer (score 2):

Two existing cookbooks for Jenkins would be the Chef Software cookbook (https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/jenkins) and mine (https://github.com/poise/jenkins).

In the future, you can use Google to find things like this or just search https://supermarket.chef.io/.